# How to pass Date as parameter to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

We areable to pass the integer values as part of inline params but not date..

We are trying it like this.

```
"script": {
                  "inline": "if ((doc['enddate'].date >= param1) && (doc['enddate'].date <= param2)) { return param2 }",
                  "params": {
                    "param1": new DateTime(),
                    "param2": new DateTime(doc['enddate'].date).plusDays(+1)
                  }
                }
```

Comment: The parameters must be external values, they cannot reference document fields. You're trying to compare `enddate` with itself? Not sure what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: Sorry I edited the question :) It should compare it to DateTime.now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reference document fields in inline parameters and in your case you don't really need any parameters. I suggest doing it the following way:

```
            "script": {
              "inline": "def now = new DateTime(); def tomorrow = now.plusDays(1); if ((doc['enddate'].date >= now) && (doc['enddate'].date <= tomorrow)) { return tomorrow }"
            }
```

Note that you still need to return something in case the condition is not satisfied.